# Install libgtk-3-dev on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, apt-get, ubuntu-20.04

I would like to write a GUI in cpp. As far as I know gtk is a nice solution for this. Sadly it appears to me that gtk is no longer available under Ubuntu 20.04. (I am using Xubuntu if this matters)

Executing: `sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev`

Leads to:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.24.20-0ubuntu1) but 3.24.20-1 is to be installed
                Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 2.15.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libfontconfig1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.40.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.57.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.41) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxi-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.24.20-0ubuntu1) but 3.24.20-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I added "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main" as suggested and tried again resulting in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 2.15.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libfontconfig1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.40.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.57.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.41) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxi-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.24.20-0ubuntu1) but 3.24.20-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am looking for a solution to install libgtk-3-dev.

Comment: I did uninstall girl1.2-gtk-3.0 and reinstalled it and now it is no longer on the list. Anyway... uninstalling girl1.2-gtk-3.0 uninstalled many other packages as well. Is there any way to reinstall all those packages together with girl1.2-gtk-3.0 (I fixed it for now by reinstalling every package manually)

Comment: Note to self: [Read carefully](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#additional-linux-requirements), you don't need to install those if you're not building a Linux desktop app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the proper version of the library libgtk-3-dev and related dependencies are not in the main focal repository yet. My solution was to add focal-updates repo. You can do it through GUI (Software&Update) or by manually editing file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and adding following line:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main
```

An update of repo list can be necessary (if you are working from command line):

```
sudo apt update
```

Then I was able to install the library (I used Synaptic manager) without any problems.
And finally I have disabled the focal-updates repo to stay just with release repo as before, not to automatically update other not-yet-released libraries.

Comment: Hey could you elaborate on why it is important to stay with main? Adding the repository doesn't sound "not-main" since it has "main" in it's name. I don't know much about it, but your answer looks like a solution to me so far :)

Comment: I have corrected the last sentence. It is just to stay with the stable release repository. Otherwise it could automatically update also other things, I suppose. But maybe I am wrong. See Ubuntu repo description e.g. here: [ubuntu.se](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279002/what-is-the-difference-between-suite-and-suite-security-repositories-in-apt)

Comment: Thank you! This removed at least one item from the long list of unmet dependencies. Sadly is still doesn't work. I added the result to the question so everyone can see the current state.

Comment: Thank you !! ... you saved the day ... it also works for Ubuntu 22 ... but I wonder why if it's a main package update then it's excluded from the default Ubuntu installation? ... Ubuntu is nice but sometimes also crazy ... I will go back to Debian and install it on my laptop next time

Comment: After changing `/etc/apt/sources.list` need to issue `sudo apt update` command to apply changes in repositories. This solution is working for Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure I have all the required dependencies, make sure to install the specific version required. The dependencies can be found here on [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgtk-3-dev) 's website

If the dependencies can not be found in the apt repository, you can always download the source files for each missing package from their respective websites, and build libgtk from source.

You most likely have a package that's incompatible with one of the others needed installed however it would require a bit more digging to find the root.

Comment: Those packages couldn't be installed also because of unmet dependencies.. libcairo libatk libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libxi-dev
The rest are installed now. I don't think that this helps, because if they could've been installed ubuntu would've done it on its own

Comment: What happens when you try to install the missing dependencies, are they not found, or are they not installed because of more missing dependencies? Building from source is probably going to be easiest option as It could take a while to find the root of your issue, either they removed some packages from the repo or you have incompatible ones. I will however try and install it on my an ubuntu build and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I have 0 issues installing it.... Try using `apt-get check` or running the install with `--fix-broken`. There's also a build-dep command which may or may not help. You'll need to add deb-src repos to use the build-dep command switch for apt-get.

Comment: It's also failing cause of missing dependencies. Are you running ubuntu20.04 or?

Comment: Yes I am running ubuntu 20.04, focal. there's got to be  something wrong with your environment, broken packages most likely, you could try `dpkg -C` to check for broken packages, or `dpkg --configure -a` in case maybe an update was interrupted ?

Comment: I figure you've probably tried this or similar but it always helps to try `apt-get clean ;  apt-get update; apt-get -f install`

Comment: Also does `apt-mark showhold` show that there's any packages on hold? If so removing those packages could fix the issue.

Comment: All commands you mentioned had no or no meaningful output. dpkg -C, dpkg --configure -a (which I tried before) has and had no output as well, clean had no output, update as usual and -f didn't change the result. apt-mark showhold is empty